# React Js - get json array Image to JSX page of react dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, image, webpack

```
state = {
  products: [
    {
      img: "'./images/heartstud.jpg'",
      name: "Heart Earrings",
      price: "1.99",
      total: "3.98",
      count: 2,
      description:
        "Yellow Chimes Crystals from Classic Designer Gold Plated Stylish Hoop Earrings for Women and Girls",
    },
    {
      img: "./images/heartstud.jpg",
      name: "Orange",
      attribution: "visualhunt",
      price: "0.99",
      count: 1,
      description:
        "PANASH Woman's Stylish/Fashion Gold-plated Beaded Handcrafted Chandbalis Trendy Party/Festive/Wedding Wear Earrings",
    },
    {
      img: "./images/heartstud.jpg",
      name: "Pear",
      price: "6.00",
      count: 4,
      description:
        "Valentine Gift By Shining Diva Italian Designer Non Precious Metal Jewellery Set for Women",
    },
  ],
};
```

My HTML goes like this where I want to call Image from the above product JSON array but using this requires I am only able to give it statically and not from the array

```
<div class="row">
  {this.state.products.map((product) => (
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src={require("./images/ring.jpg")} alt="" />
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">{product.name}</a>
          </h4>
          <h5>${product.price}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{product.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>;
```

In place of static `Imageurl` i want to use `{product.img}` as using for other elements.Using require I am able to get static Image but not able to map from state json data...kindly help.

Comment: Using `src={require(\`${product.img}\`)}` should work

Answer (score 0):

When working with Webpack (assuming you [bootstrapped your project with CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/)), a path like `./images/ring.jpg` is only available in build time.

In runtime, use:

```
// product.img = "./images/heartstud.jpg";
<img class="card-img-top" src={require(product.img)} alt="" />
```

Or import paths beforehand:

```
import heartstud from "./images/heartstud.jpg";

// v generated from webpack in build
console.log(heartstud); // /heartstud.84287d09.jpg

state = {
  products: [
    {
      img: heartstud,
    },
  ],
};

<img class="card-img-top" src={product.img} alt="" />
```

See [Adding Images in CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

> Note that you have a typo: "'./images/heartstud.jpg'" (an extra `'`)

Comment: require(`${product.img}`) - using runtime means i need to declare anywhere? As i want to show different images import option will not work

Comment: using `require` you provide the path, see updated answer.

Comment: If you know the available paths beforehand, `import` is a better option, `require` is for dynamics path i.e you don't know the path in build time. But they both work.

Comment: while trying first option below error is coming :Error: Cannot find module ''./images/heartstud.jpg''
webpackEmptyContext
D:/Ria/shopping-app/src/components sync:4
Anonymous function
D:/Ria/shopping-app/src/components/Content.jsx:107
  104 |          <button>Reset</button>
  105 |        </div>
  106 | 
> 107 |        <div class="row">
      | ^
  108 |          {this.state.products.map((product) => (
  109 |            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
  110 |              <div class="card h-100">

Comment: Please don't use comments to describe your problems, edit your question

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
          name: "Heart Earrings",
          price: "1.99",
          total: "3.98",
          count: 2,
          description:
            "Yellow Chimes Crystals from Classic Designer Gold Plated Stylish Hoop Earrings for Women and Girls"
        },
        {
          img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
          name: "Orange",
          attribution: "visualhunt",
          price: "0.99",
          count: 1,
          description:
            "PANASH Woman's Stylish/Fashion Gold-plated Beaded Handcrafted Chandbalis Trendy Party/Festive/Wedding Wear Earrings"
        },
        {
          img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771766",
          name: "Pear",
          price: "6.00",
          count: 4,
          description:
            "Valentine Gift By Shining Diva Italian Designer Non Precious Metal Jewellery Set for Women"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row">
        {this.state.products.map(product => (
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src={product.img}
                alt=""
                width="100px"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{product.name}</h4>
                <h5>${product.price}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{product.description}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Check this it's working fine. No need to add require for iteration. working link [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-roentgen-dqfoj?file=/src/App.js:51-1773)